# Is there an api of stopbadwares to check if a url is dangerous?

Tags: php, security

I want to implement the functionality of [www.stopbadwares.com](http://www.stopbadwares.com) in my web app using php so I can pass a url and check if it's contains badwares or it's dangerous for use.  Is there an api, or class, or something to do that?  If there isn't, is there a similar service to protect my users from sharing bad links?

Note: Firefox , Chrome, and Safari use the same service ( maybe it's of google too )

Answer (score 4):

from their site:

> To be clear, we do not have a public
>   API for access to our data. Google
>   offers the [Safe Browsing API](http://code.google.com/apis/safebrowsing/) for
>   access to their data, which they also
>   make available to us through our
>   Clearinghouse.

http://blog.stopbadware.org/2008/09/12/mse360-uses-our-name-in-vain

http://code.google.com/apis/safebrowsing/

Comment: you mean after he asked "is there an api of stopbadwares?" and "i want to use the functionality of www.stopbadwares.com" ? i answered both questions in any case.

Answer (score 1):

[Yes, there is](http://code.google.com/apis/safebrowsing/).

To clarify, this isn't StopBadware's data.